# In MSBuild, can I use the String.Replace function on a MetaData item?

Tags: msbuild

In MSBuild v4 one can use functions (like `string.replace`) on *Properties*. But how can I use functions on *Metadata*?

I'd like to use the `string.replace` function as below:

```xml
<Target Name="Build">
  <Message Text="@(Files->'%(Filename).Replace(&quot;.config&quot;,&quot;&quot;)')" />
</Target>
```

Unfortunately this outputs as (not quite what I was going for):

```
log4net.Replace(".config","");ajaxPro.Replace(".config","");appSettings.Replace(".config","");cachingConfiguration20.Replace(".config","");cmsSiteConfiguration.Replace(".config","");dataProductsGraphConfiguration.Replace(".config","");ajaxPro.Replace(".config","");appSettings.Replace(".config","");cachingConfiguration20.Replace(".config","");cmsSiteConfiguration
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Is it desired end result to remove the extension from the items in a item group? You might want to approach this as create a new item group from the original item group modifying the entries. A transform or a custom task if more control is needed could do this.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this problem in the end? How? I have a similar issue: property definition does not work as Target has a file list as Input, not a single filename.

Answer (score 81):

You can do this with a little bit of trickery:

```
$([System.String]::Copy('%(Filename)').Replace('config',''))
```

Basically, we call the static method 'Copy' to create a new string (for some reason it doesn't like it if you just try `$('%(Filename)'.Replace('.config',''))`), then call the replace function on the string.

The full text should look like this:

```
<Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="@(Files->'$([System.String]::Copy(&quot;%(Filename)&quot;).Replace(&quot;.config&quot;,&quot;&quot;))')" />
</Target>
```

---

**Edit:** MSBuild 12.0 seems to have broken the above method. As an alternative, we can add a new metadata entry to all existing `Files` items. We perform the replace while defining the metadata item, then we can access the modified value like any other metadata item.

**e.g.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <Files Include="Alice.jpg"/>
        <Files Include="Bob.not-config.gif"/>
        <Files Include="Charlie.config.txt"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <!-- 
            Modify all existing 'Files' items so that they contain an entry where we have done our replace.
            Note: This needs to be done WITHIN the '<Target>' (it's a requirment for modifying existing items like this
            -->
            <Files>
                <FilenameWithoutConfig>$([System.String]::Copy('%(Filename)').Replace('.config', ''))</FilenameWithoutConfig>
            </Files>
        </ItemGroup>

        <Message Text="@(Files->'%(FilenameWithoutConfig)')" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Result:

```
D:\temp>"c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /nologo test.xml
Build started 2015/02/11 11:19:10 AM.
Project "D:\temp\test.xml" on node 1 (default targets).
Build:
  Alice;Bob.not-config;Charlie
Done Building Project "D:\temp\test.xml" (default targets).
```

Comment: using msbuild 12.0 (and .net 4.0) I get "%(Filename);%(Filename);.." as result. what's wrong with my environment?

Comment: @nilleb Can you post the relevant code somewhere (e.g. pastebin.com) and I'll see if I can spot what is wrong

Comment: I've posted an alternative answer for MSBuild 12.0

Comment: @nilleb It seems they have changed around the evaluation order in 2012, I'll post a workaround for 2012 shortly

Comment: I'd suggest using `$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('%(MetadataName)', '').Replace('foo', 'bar'))`instead of String.Copy, in order to avoid actually creating a copy of the string's data.

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible to make functon in MSBuild so I could have simple ReplaceString(%(FileName)) instead of this long line ?

Comment: For information: there's a related open issue on MSBuild's GitHub repository: [Metadata should support instance methods](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/1155).

Answer (score 47):

I needed to do something similar, the following worked for me.

```
<Target Name="Build">
  <Message Text="@(Files->'%(Filename)'->Replace('.config', ''))" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This looks be the most succinct answer.

Comment: This looks like the best answer to me.  Short and sweet.

Comment: This makes use of the MSBuild Item Functions, and I'd say it's the cleanest and most idiomatic. It also doesn't incur a string copying like the alternatives. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-functions

Answer (score 24):

Those functions works in properties only (as I know). So create target which will perform operation throw batching:

```
<Target Name="Build"                                 
      DependsOnTargets="ProcessFile" />

<Target Name="ProcessFile"
       Outputs="%(Files.Identity)">
   <PropertyGroup>
       <OriginalFileName>%(Files.Filename)</OriginalFileName>
       <ModifiedFileName>$(OriginalFileName.Replace(".config",""))</ModifiedFileName>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <Message Text="$(ModifiedFileName)" Importance="High"/>
</Target>
```

Do you really need in your example such kind of task? I mean there exists [MSBuild Well-known Item Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx)

**EDIT:** I should specify that this task processes **all items** in @(Files).

Comment: I did not know you could create a property based on another property. very very useful!

Comment: Afraid not :(  Files.FileName is a collection, but $ModifiedFileName is only a single value in the end. I need the "Replace" to be run on every item in 'Files'.

Comment: 1) It processes each item in @(Files).

Comment: 2) Do you mean that in metadata you store several values? Please, give an example of items you use.

Comment: Is this a MSBuild 4.0 only trick?  Or does it work with MSBuild 3.5 (2.0)? The .Replace being the operative command of interest.

Comment: Of all the options I tried to get a Replace to work, it was this one that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i dont think you can use functions directly with itemgroups and metadata (that would be easy)
However you can use batching:

Taking the ideas from this post:
[array-iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045821/msbuild-array-iteration)

I was trying to trim an itemgroup to send to a commandline tool (i needed to lose .server off the filename)

```
<Target Name="ProcessFile"  DependsOnTargets="FullPaths">

    <ItemGroup>
        <Environments Include="$(TemplateFolder)\$(Branch)\*.server.xml"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <MSBuild Projects=".\Configure.msbuild" 
             Properties="CurrentXmlFile=%(Environments.Filename)"
             Targets="Configure"/>

</Target>

<Target Name="Configure" DependsOnTargets="FullPaths">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Trimmed>$(CurrentXmlFile.Replace('.server',''))</Trimmed>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Message Text="Trimmed: $(Trimmed)"/>

    <Exec  Command="ConfigCmd $(Trimmed)"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

For MSBuild 12.0, here's an alternative.

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="$([System.String]::Copy(&quot;%(Files.Filename)&quot;).Replace(&quot;.config&quot;,&quot;&quot;))" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem (except with MakeRelative), so I passed with another solution : Using good old CreateItem that take a string and transform to Item :)

```
        <ItemGroup>
            <_ToUploadFTP Include="$(PublishDir)**\*.*"></_ToUploadFTP>
        </ItemGroup>
        <CreateItem Include="$([MSBuild]::MakeRelative('c:\$(PublishDir)','c:\%(relativedir)%(filename)%(_ToUploadFTP.extension)'))">
            <Output ItemName="_ToUploadFTPRelative" TaskParameter="Include"/>
        </CreateItem>
        <FtpUpload Username="$(UserName)" 
                   Password="$(UserPassword)" 
                   RemoteUri="$(FtpHost)"
                   LocalFiles="@(_ToUploadFTP)"
                   RemoteFiles="@(_ToUploadFTPRelative->'$(FtpSitePath)/%(relativedir)%(filename)%(extension)')"
                   UsePassive="$(FtpPassiveMode)" ></FtpUpload>
```