# MsBuild Condition Evaluate Property Contains

Tags: msbuild

Attempting to create an itemgroup for use in a target where the file types are - Filename.CSS.ASPX

```
<Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Project $(ProjectName) Test PostBuild" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="%(Content.FullPath)" Condition="%(Extension) == '.aspx' AND %(Filename.Contains(css))" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

On Compile;

```
Error   1   Expected "%(Filename.Contains(css))" to evaluate to a boolean instead of "%(Filename.Contains(css))", in condition "%(Extension) == '.aspx' AND %   (Filename.Contains(css))".  C:\Projects\TestProj\TestProj\TestProj.csproj   58  38  TestProj
```

Any advice on expanding properties for evaluation?

Comment: You'll probably want to make sure that any string literals that you pass to property functions as parameters are properly quoted. `$(Property.Contains('literal'))` not `$(Property.Contains(literal))`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use string functions (like `Contains` in your code) only for **properties**, not for **item metadata**. But you tried to invoke `Contains` for `%(Filename)` and this is a metadata of `Content` item.

To get more details see [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473). The last paragraph strictly says:

> Property functions may not appear within metadata values. For example,
>   `%(Compile.FullPath.Substring(0,3))`
>   is not allowed.

However, you can use static methods of `Regex` class. I believe the following code is what you wanted:

```
<Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Project $(ProjectName) Test PostBuild" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="%(Content.FullPath)" Condition=" $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('%(FullPath)', '.+\.css\.aspx')) " Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

If not, you can modify the regular expression in any way you need.

Answer (score 14):

In answer to similar question [In MSBuild, can I use the String.Replace function on a MetaData item?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904902/959779) was suggestion to use `[System.String]::Copy()` as workaround to access non static `System.String` methods.

So code can be rewritten to:

```
    <Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Text="Project $(ProjectName) Test PostBuild" Importance="high" />
        <Message Text="%(Content.FullPath)" Condition="%(Content.Extension) == '.aspx' AND $([System.String]::Copy(%(Content.Filename)).Contains('css'))" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
```