# Accessing PreProcessor definitions in MSBuild post-build events

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, preprocessor, post-build-event

Given a PreProcessor definition like the following:

`<PreprocessorDefinitions>%(PreprocessorDefinitions);ENABLE_DEBUGGING=1;</PreProcessorDefinitions>`

Is it possible to determine the value of ENABLE_DEBUGGING during an MSBuild post-build event?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the probably multiple ways to do this; will only work if the ClCompile ItemGroup contains items, in other words when there are files to compile, and if they all have the same value for PreprocessorDefinitions; it stores the number found after the `ENABLE_DEBUGGING=` string in the DebugVal property.:

```
<Target Name="CheckValue" BeforeTargets="BuildGenerateSources">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreProc>%(ClCompile.PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreProc>
    <DebugVal>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match( $(PreProc), 'ENABLE_DEBUGGING=(\d)' ).Groups[ 1 ].Value )</DebugVal>
    </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="ENABLE_DEBUGGING = $(DebugVal)" />
</Target>
```

Inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129831/msbuild-condition-evaluate-property-contains) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103026/in-msbuild-can-i-use-the-string-replace-function-on-a-metadata-item)