# MSBUILD: "The target does not exist in the project." after modifying DependsOnTarget

Tags: msbuild

After adding to .csproj

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CompileDependsOn>$(CompileDependsOn.ToString())</CompileDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm getting `error MSB4057: The target does not exist in the project.`

```
error MSB4057: The target "CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive;
...other stuff...
;" does not exist in the project.
```

Nevertheless string between quotes looks correct.

**Edit:** Looks like duplication of [strange behavior of Property functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023681/strange-behavior-of-property-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Like in accepted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024381/915546 solution is to use `[MSBuild]::Unescape` function:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CompileDependsOn>$([MSBuild]::Unescape(CompileDependsOn.ToString()))</CompileDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```