# MSBuild: Stepping through an array

Tags: arrays, loops, msbuild

I have a script that does a directory listing and puts it in with the newest entry first.  I then want to step through the array looking into that directory for a file and if it exists, stop, but if it doesn't, go to the next item of the array.  There are many directories under C:\Foo

How do I do that?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RootDir>C:\Foo</RootDir>
    <OutputFile>C:\Output.txt</OutputFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Generate">
    <Exec Command="dir &quot;$(RootDir)&quot; /ad /o-d /b > &quot;$(OutputFile)&quot;" />
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(OutputFile)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="OutputLines"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <Message Text="@(OutputLines->'%(Identity)', '%0a%0d')" />
</Target>
```

So OutputLines has the array and I want to start at the first location of the array (i.e. C:\Foo\Dir1) and look for the file abc.zip.  If that exists, then copy that file to a different location and if not go to the next item (i.e. C:\Foo\Dir2).

Thanks.  Any help is appreciated.  Still very new to MSBuild.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045821/msbuild-array-iteration

Answer (score 0):

You've created a list of items, which is a kind of array for sure. However you don't process an array (or list of items) in MSBuild the same as you would if you were programming. Instead, try to use the wildcards to specifically look for only the information you want like so:

```
<!-- This replaces the Exec and the ReadLinesFromFile tasks in your target -->
<ItemGroup>
  <OutputLines Include="$(RootDir)**\abc.zip"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then use the items you discover in that new item list to do your processing.

Comment: The only problem is that if I use it the way you have it, I get nothing back. If I make it $(Rootdir)\\**\abc.zip, I get a list of files that I want, but the very last entry is what I want to use. I am not sure how to "use" that last entry to copy it from that location to another one. So how would I take that last entry in the list and copy it? Thanks

Comment: What differentiates the first/last entry? Is it that you want the latest datestamped file? In that case you might be able to take advantage of the Common MSBuild Item Metadata (here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx). You might want to use the Message task with a Conditional (using the date metadata) to sort out how to get the file you want. Then use the Copy task with that same conditional to copy that file.

Comment: Yes the "latest" entry is the one directory that was the latest created (the newest time stamp).  Also, I don't understand what you mean with the conditional and how to set that up to get the directory that was created with the latest (i.e. newest date) time stamp.

Comment: Okay, I have the entries sorted and I want to take the very first entry in the list and copy that file and then stop.  I created that line with <Message Text="$(RootDir)\%(DirList.Identity)\Cover\Files\abc.zip />.  There are many entries after that, but I only want to take the "first" one and then copy it.  How do I get that first entry, copy it and then stop?